# Angular Universal doesn't add/update meta tags from WebService call for Facebook share preview Image/Title/Description

Tags: angular, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

Basically I am creating a News Application in Angular 8. The news Content will be added in the admin portal and updated in server. On website view, We make API call to fetch the news data from server. All working fine, Just i want to share those news in Social Media Sites like FB, Twitter, Whatsapp etc.

Therefore I implemented (https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-sharebuttons/#/) but my bad!:( It doesn't update the Facebook OG Tags of (Image, Url, Description, Title). After googling I got to know this could only be achieved by making the angular application render from Server Side using Angular Universal (https://medium.com/@maciejtreder/angular-server-side-rendering-with-ng-toolkit-universal-c08479ca688) through node js express server.

Then I thought this will fix all the issues, alas! the problem persists. It doesn't alter/update the meta tags after the webservice call is made. Only static content provided in the meta tags are getting updated by not dynamic content.On Clicking every news I should provide new Title, Description, Image URL but that wasn't working.

I googled to find whether I am the one facing similar situation. But I could see plenty of them, and all look for the same but nowhere any crystal clear answer or any working solutions are found. I write this query to find anyone to give solid answer whether it has any possible solutions or any work around or this could achievable in first place

--------In Construcor

```
      [
      {name: 'description', content: 'Title and Meta tags examples'},      
      {httpEquiv: 'Content-Type', content: 'text/html'},
      {property: 'og:title', content: "My Text"},
      {property: 'og:type', content: "TEst"},
      {property: 'og:image', content:"TEst"},
      {property: 'og:url', content: "TEst"},
      {property: 'og:description', content: "description"},
      {property: 'twitter:card', content: "description"}

   ]



---------IN ngOnInit     

 this.homeService.GetNews(id).subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        if (result) {
          this.newsDetails = result;
          if(this.newsDetails.length > 0) {

            this.meta.updateTag({property: 'og:title', content: this.newsDetails[0].HeadLine});
            this.meta.updateTag({property: 'og:description', content: this.newsDetails[0].HeadLine });
            this.meta.updateTag({property: 'og:url', content:  this.ShareUrl });
            this.meta.updateTag({property: 'og:image', content: 'http://admin.xyz.com/CategoryFiles/'+this.newsDetails[0].ImageThumb});
            this.meta.updateTag({property: 'twitter:card', content: this.newsDetails[0].HeadLine });
          }

        }
      })
```

Comment: Did you have any joy with this in the end?

Comment: Were you able to slve this issue?